# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una vista dinámica en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, vistas

Estoy haciendo un sistema de nómina de trabajo de la Universidad, y estoy utilizando SQL Server y Visual Studio para ello. Lo que quiero es realizar una vista que varíe por cada usuario y que esta muestre por cada uno en particular, el nombre de usuario, un historial de los ingresos realizados a su sueldo (horas extras por ej), un historial de las deducciones que se le restan a su sueldo (impuestos) y la fecha en la que se hizo cada cosa, puesto que puede variar por mes y también por empleado. No sé bien como podría hacerlo y necesito un empujón ahí, si lo podría hacer con un procedimiento almacenado o algo donde utilice parámetros.

Es decir, lo que necesito es una aclaración de como podría lograr hacerlo, que podría utilizar para llevar a cabo lo que quiero en esas 2 tecnologías que menciono arriba.

[image: Aquí adjunto mi modelo relacional de base de datos, por si le quieren echar una ojeada.]

Comment: Solo quieres que la respuesta se vea como resultado de un Execute de SQL o quieres que este en una vista (View).

Comment: Quiero que esté en una vista, pero si se puede mostrar como resultado de un Execute, estaría bien también

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde se las vistas no trabajan con parámetros, pero tienes 2 soluciones:

1. Usar un procedimiento almacenado en sql lo ejecutas `exec sp_traer_sueldo_historial @empleado=tuidempleado` , como dato extra en tu código necesitarías un sqlcommand y un sqldatareader
2. Usar una función que te devuelva una tabla (se asemeja mas a la vista)

`CREATE FUNCTION fn_traersueldo_historial
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @empleado varchar(60)--no se el tipo de datos de la columna
)
RETURNS (/*en esta sección tu consulta usando los parámetros que desees, por ejemplo*/ SELECT NOM_EMPLEADO,FECHA,MONTO FROM EMPLEADO E JOIN REGISTRO_TRANSACCION T ON E.ID_EMPLEADO=T.ID_EMPLEADO WHERE E.ID_EMPLEADO=@empleado)` 
Esto en sql lo ejecutas `SELECT * FROM fn_traersueldo_historial('tuidempleado')` en el código necesitarías un sqlcommand y un sqldatareader.

Por otro lado, no entiendo bien si tus usuarios son los empleados en sí, de ser así y si estas usando login sql para cada usuario tienes otra solución usando una vista y es hacer uso de SUSER_NAME() que devuelve el nombre de inicio de sesión del usuario sql, es decir si tu "Empleado" tiene id "JPEREZ" y tiene su propio login sql también con nombre "JPEREZ" con el que inicia sesión en la aplicación y en la base de datos puedes crear una vista con la consulta `SELECT * FROM EMPLEADO WHERE ID_EMPLEADO=SUSER_NAME()` 
 Espero haberme explicado

Answer (score 1):

En SQL Server tienes Funciones con Valores de Tabla en Línea, te devuelve un tipo de dato TABLE y puedes realizar consultas sobre el resultado.

Ejemplo

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindInvalidEmails(@ModifiedSince datetime)   
RETURNS TABLE (  
   CustomerId int,  
   EmailAddress nvarchar(4000)  
)  
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyClrCode.UserDefinedFunctions.[FindInvalidEmails];  
go  

SELECT * FROM FindInvalidEmails('2000-01-01');  
go
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-table-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017